# Why does my variable value never change?

Tags: java

In my code I have the variable `randomNumber`, which should change, but it never does. Why?

```
import java.util.Random;
import  java.util.Scanner;

public class NimGame
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
        Random myRandom = new Random();

        int playerCount = 1;
        int stonesRemoved = 0;
        int randomNumber;

        randomNumber = myRandom.nextInt(15) + 16; // Selects a random number between 15-30 as the number of stones.

        System.out.println("You will be playing with: " + randomNumber + " stones.");

        System.out.println("Each player can take 1, 2 or 3 stones when it is your turn.");
        System.out.println("Player who takes the last stone looses.");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         while (true)
         {
            StoneRemover (randomNumber, playerCount);
           randomNumber = randomNumber - stonesRemoved;

           System.out.println("There are now: " + randomNumber + " stones");

          if (randomNumber == 0)
          {
            if (playerCount == 1)
            {
              System.out.println("Player 1 lost!");
            }

            else
            {
              System.out.println("Player 2 lost!");
            }
            break;
          }
          playerCount ++;

          if (playerCount > 2)
           {
             playerCount = 1;
           }
         }
         input.close();
    }

   public static int StoneRemover (int stonesRemoved, int playerCount)
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       while (true)
       {      
          System.out.print("How many stones does player " + playerCount + " want to take? ");
          stonesRemoved = input.nextInt(); 
         if (stonesRemoved > 3 || stonesRemoved == 0)
          {
            System.out.println("You did not select a correct number of stones to remove.");
            System.out.println("Try Again!!");
          }

         else 
          {
            break;
          }
       } 
       return stonesRemoved;
   }
}

      //Every time I run the code, the randomNumber does not update to the new number after the user retrieves 1,2, or 3 stones. Why is this happening
```

Comment: The real question is not related to random numbers at all. You only use the random number generator once and never again. The real question is: "why does my variable never change".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the returned value from the `stonesRemoved` function:

```
stonesRemoved = StoneRemover(randomNumber, playerCount);
```

Or you could do:

```
randomNumber -= StoneRemover(randomNumber, playerCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't work because you did not change the variable `stonesRemoved` at all. It stays 0, always!

"But no! I changed it in the `StoneRemover` method! Didn't I?" you might ask.

Well what you did here:

```
stonesRemoved = input.nextInt();
```

is *not* changing the `stoneRemoved` variable that you used in the main method i.e.:

```
randomNumber = randomNumber - stonesRemoved; // <-- not this one!
```

This is because you passed the *value* instead of the reference of `stonesRemoved` to the method, so changing it inside the `StoneRemover` method has no effect on the `stonesRemoved` variable in the main method. What you can do is this:

Change this line:

```
StoneRemover (randomNumber, playerCount);
```

to this:

```
stonesRemoved = StoneRemover (randomNumber, playerCount);
```

And it should work!